# How to change default location of AVDs on Mac OS X

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio with my macbook (OS X 10.10).

I find that the default location where AVD Manager create AVDs is `~/.android`.  But my ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set to `~/Android/android-sdk`,which means the directory to create an AVD should be `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android`(that is `~/Android/android-sdk/.android`).

When I use `emulator -avd` command, however, the directory the command searches is `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd` rather than the directory where the AVDs are located. As a result, there would be an error says:

```
PANIC: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_21.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)
```

Can anyone tell me how to change the default directory where to create AVDs so that the location where AVDs are in and the location `emulator` command searches would be the same one.